# SQLCEException was unhandled: Internal Error: Cannot open the shared memory region

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to do a TableAdapter.Fill(dataTable) and it fails with the above error. Here is the code in ...DataSet.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Fill, true)]
public virtual int Fill(ZenwareDataSet.BatchPDADataTable dataTable) {

     this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
     if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true)) {
         dataTable.Clear();
     }
     int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable); //  <---Fails here.
     return returnValue;
}
```

This is generated code. Maybe there is something that I need to change? I am wondering if my app has multiple connections to the database. What can this be? Thanks for any help you can provide.

- Windows Mobile 6.1 device (Trimble Juno SB)
- SQLServerCompact 3.5 Service Pack 2
- Microsoft .NET CF 3.5

Comment: I know similar questions are out there. But this is on a win mo device. Sometimes it seems intermediate, but I can repro it with certain calls from my app. Once the problem is there, it continues until i reboot the device. During debugging, it seems like the problem went away, like if there is a long enough delay due to breakpoints, then there is no problem. The above function seems to get called 3 times.

Comment: I changed the SQL Server CE for WM Devices version to SP1 and the problem seemed to go away, however it is now back. Is anyone else seeing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer to this question is to make sure nothing keeps a connection open. Since I had inherited this problem, I was not aware of everything that could hold an open connection. Once I centralized the connection in a single function I have not seen the error.

Comment: Also, use a singleton for your class with the connection. Perform the "connection.open" only once in your app.

Answer (score 1):

OK, do I feel stupid. Even with previous answer, I still was occasionally seeing the above issue. Finally I am addressing it, and all I can say is, "Duh". I wasn't closing my readers, in this case, SqlCeDataReader. Once I close the reader, everything is fine. What makes this problem hard to figure out is that once you forget to close a reader in your application, it is the next time you try to do a database operation that you see the issue. By then you have forgotten that the reader was not closed previously.

I hope this helps someone. I did not find the answer anywhere else I looked, so vote this answer up if it does help.